# Canon flatbed scanner does not work on 32 bit Linux

Tags: drivers, scanner, canon, sane, xsane

I'm trying to run `Canon Flatbed Scanner Unit 101` on 32 bit Linux. I can use this scanner on a custom Linux distro but I can't run it on Ubuntu 32-bit.

All the config files are the same. I also installed the driver provided by Canon but still no luck. I get `Failed to open device. canondr:libusb:001:002. Error during device I/O`

I could not find error logs. Here is the error screen:

[image: Error]

How can I make this scanner work?

Edit:

This is my Linux version (ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-i386):

```
Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-45-generic #48~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 18:03:19 UTC 2019 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

This is the wprking laptop kernel:

```
Linux l006198022.xxx.gov 4.11.3-2.g596757c-pae #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon May 29 00:20:18 UTC 2017 (596757c) i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

And I'm downloading the scanner driver from [this link](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/products/document-scanners/accessories/flatbed-scanner-unit-101.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=windows%2010%20(64-bit))

These are the `cat /etc/os-release` outputs:

Not working laptop:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Working laptop:

```
NAME=openSUSE
VERSION="13.1 (Bottle)"
VERSION_ID="13.1"
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE 13.1 (Bottle) (i586)"
ID=opensuse
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:opensuse:opensuse:13.1"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.opensuse.org"
HOME_URL="https://opensuse.org/"
ID_LIKE="suse"
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned what release of Ubuntu you're using, nor where the package comes from (a link maybe helpful). Details of the *custom* distro may also be helpful (ie. what type of stack, age of stack etc esp. if contrasted to the unspecified release of Ubuntu you are trying to use)

Comment: @guiverc Added more info. Thanks

Comment: You still haven't provided your Ubuntu release details, you provided a kernel which does let me guess, but it's better if we aren't guessing.  Your software stack is made up of more than just the kernel...

Comment: @guiverc Yes you are right. Added (it's `ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-i386`)

Comment: Have you tried using `gdebi` to install instead of `dpkg`? Although, I don't see any errors, `gdebi` allows you to install from a deb file but it automatically takes care of dependencies and other stuff like `apt` does.